# FirstOrDefault on collection of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have something like the following classes:

```
public class Animal
{
    ...
}

public class Cow : Animal
{
    ...
}

public class AnimalCollection : List<Animal>
{
    public Animal GetFirstAnimal<T>()
    {
        foreach(Animal animal in this)
        {
            if(animal is T)
                return T as Animal
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

A few questions:
Is it possible to use FirstOrDefault on the collection instead of having the GetFirstAnimal() method? What would be the syntax if you can? Also which would be the most efficient? It isn't going to be a massive collection.

Alternatively, is there a better way of doing the same thing all together?

Comment: FYI, that's not a collection of classes, it's a collection of objects.

Comment: It's late and I have man flu, have edited to correct

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var firstCow = animals.OfType<Cow>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yep - I did indeed mean FirstOrDefault.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. Although I was originally thinking along the lines of using FirstOrDefault with a predicate i'm now thinking using OfType might fit in better

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using `OfType` <s>which actually iterates the entire list</s>, you could use the overload of `FirstOrDefault` and pass in a predicate:

```
var firstAnimal = animals.FirstOrDefault( x => x is Animal ) as Animal;
```

**Edit**: as correctly noted by @Lee in the comments, `OfType` does not iterate the entire list; rather `OfType` will only iterate the collection until the `FirstOrDefault` predicate is matched.

Comment: Wouldn't SingleOrDefault also have to iterate the entire list in order to make the guarantee of there being no more than one item which fits the predicate?

Comment: Yep - My my bad. Mean FirstOrDefault.

Comment: `OfType` does not iterate the whole list, it is lazy in the same way as `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @Lee - great clarification! A bit of MSDN and a quick test... OfType will not iterate the whole list. Rather, OfType will only iterate as far as it needs until the predicate of the FirstOrDefault is met.

Comment: The OP is filtering from a generic collection of 'T' which could be a Cow, a Dog, etc... and wants to return an Animal so you need to cast the Cow (or whatever was found) back to an Animal.

Comment: @MetroSmurf: I still don't get it. Since `animals` is a `List<Animal>`, `FirstOrDefault` will return a value with *static type* `Animal`. Yes, the *dynamic type* might be a subtype of Animal, but a cast only changes the static type (which is already correct).